# Position the header of the table in the fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to position the header of the table in the fixed position.
the header of the table is somewhere near the bottom of the page. When the jquery get is succeeded, the header go up according to the data. So I want to position the header as a fixed position.

the output should be like this[image]

I tried modifying the position for the thead but it does not work.

my code is found below...

html code

```
<table id="topfivecountry" style="color:white;font-size:15px;">
            <thead style="position:absolute;bottom:40%;right:3%;">
                <tr>
                    <th>Top 5 countries</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
```

js code

```
$.get ({
        url:'getTopFiveCountry.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: getTopFive
    });



function getTopFive(val) {
        var countryArray = val.split('\n');
        //country is the argument that is being passed by the forEach to the callback function
        countryArray.forEach(function(country){
            $('#topfivecountry').append('<tr><td>'+country+'</td></tr>')
        });
    }
```

Comment: don't include `<tr>` when appending and append it in the thead row..

Comment: this website shows this example https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_thead.asp

Comment: When working with `<table>` and its elements (`tr`, `td`, `thead`, `tbody`, etc), never ever change the "position" attribute of any of them except the table itself. The way the table and its elements being rendered by the browsers are related to each other.

Comment: @evilReiko, I know that but the client find it not so nice as the header position change when the jquery request succeeed.

Comment: @Azhar I'd suggest that you make 2 elements: 1) First one is visible before ajax or while ajax is loading 2) once the ajax is loaded, hide the first element and show the 2nd one. This way you can control each element's CSS separately

Comment: @evilReiko, i have solved it by using two elements which is h5 and table. I position the h5 in the fixed position and when the jquery is successful, the h5 header position did not change at all

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make the header position absoluted to the table, and set the table `position: absolute; right: 3%; top: 60%;` to near the bottom of the page.

example like:

```js
$.get({
        url:'getTopFiveCountry.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: getTopFive
    });
    
var $tbody = $('#topfivecountry tbody');

getTopFive('a\nb\nc\n');

function getTopFive(val) {
        var countryArray = val.split('\n');
        //country is the argument that is being passed by the forEach to the callback function
        countryArray.forEach(function(country){
            $tbody.append('<tr><td>'+country+'</td></tr>')
        });
    }
```

```css
#topfivecountry {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  right: 3%;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.thead {
  height: 30px;
  position:absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.content {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="topfivecountry" style="color:white;font-size:15px;">
            <thead class="thead" style="">
                <tr>
                    <th>Top 5 countries</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="content">
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add a `<tbody>` tag in your HTML table and while appending specify the `<tbody>` and then append your `<tr>`.
 Now in your code, I think the country is getting appended to `<thead>` and it's  `<tr>` and that's why the header text is getting shifted.
Also remove `style="position:absolute;bottom:40%;right:3%;"` . Attached a working copy.

```js
$.get ({
        url:'getTopFiveCountry.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: getTopFive
    });


getTopFive('a\nb\nc\n');
function getTopFive(val) {
        var countryArray = val.split('\n');
        //country is the argument that is being passed by the forEach to the callback function
        countryArray.forEach(function(country){
            $('#topfivecountry > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>'+country+'</td></tr>')
        });
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="topfivecountry" style="font-size:15px;">
            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th>Top 5 countries</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
  <tbody>
     
  </tbody>
        </table>
```